# track params changes in rails active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

So i have my form and in my controller i have my update method as follows

```
def update 
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])

  if @student.update_attributes!(student_params)
    @student.read_notes = true
    #here i check if the records changed or not?
    ap @student.name_changed? 
  end
end

def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:name, :email, :age, :class)
end
```

This fails as i always get the false response each time even though i have actually made changes to the name record.

How do i actually track my changes in my record if i am updating via this way?

Answer (score 0):

When you save the record (which `update_attributes!`, `update!`, and `update` will all do), Rails' "dirty tracking" resets and you lose the ability to easily tell if anything changed. What you could do instead is use `assign_attributes`, like so:

```
def update 
  @student = Student.find(params[:id])

  @student.assign_attributes(student_params)

  if @student.name_changed?
    # ...
  end

  @student.save!
end
```

There's also an ActiveRecord method called `previous_changes`, which stores changes made after a save. [This article](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-track-changes-with-after-callbacks-in-rails-3-or-newer/) goes into detail on how to use that.

You could also simply track if the `name` parameter differs from the record's `name`, or store the value prior to the update and compare it afterward, depending on your needs.

Comment: i tried using ur example but i still get false on name_changed? why is this so? i made some edits to my question as well cos  i still kept the if @student.assign_attributes(student_params)

Comment: if i jst implement ur answer d way it is it works fine but i want to edit some information only when i am updating d attributes for @student so how do i go about this?

Comment: `name_changed?` will return false if the `name` attribute that the user submitted does not differ from the user's existing name. Now, if you want to test if *any* attributes changed, you could check that with `if @student.changed?`.